# how to access the styles from CSS

Tags: java, css, gwt, cssresource

Can we get the value from inside a css definition in the code if CSS resource is used?

e.g.

```
.iv_menu_thumbnail {  
  display: block;  
  width: 24px;  
  height: 24px;  
  margin: 3px;  
  float: left;  
  cursor: pointer;  
}`
```

Can we know via code the value of `width` and i want to access from one of my java class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Looking at the question tags it seems that you're trying to read CSS styles values from within a Java/GWT application, is that correct ? Can you elaborate a bit in your question ?

Comment: @Nico-exactly,i want to read the values from my GWT application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var width = $('.iv_menu_thumbnail').width();
console.log(width);
```

This will get the width of the element if this is what youre asking for. 
As far as I'm concerned you cannot get non numerical values from a css declaration.

But you can set your own values via jQuery using the

```
.css()
```

So it would look like this if you want to set a new css value. (or overwrite it)

```
$(someelement).css('float', 'left');
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only inspect the computed CSS property on an element where this has been applied. Like:

```
$(someElementOrId).css('width');
```

or

```
$(someElementOrId).width();
```

Note that the former and the latter differ - the former does not contain the unit of measure, the latter does.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variables in your Css Resource file and set the width attribute with that variable, and then access the width varialbe from code.

[CssResource](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource)

Css Resource file

```
@def small 1px; 
@def black #000;
border: small solid black;
```

Java Code

```
interface MyResources extends CssResource {
  int small();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...yeah i know this way.....definitions can access but i want to access the class attribute through the program....