# want to access the css styles from my java code

Tags: java, gwt, cssresource

i have a css in my GWTApplication which contains several classes in that,I want to access the class attributes through my program,is there any way to access them via java code or CssResource.
If there is any let me know with the sample code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access the styles from CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128023/how-to-access-the-styles-from-css)

Comment: You asked this exact same question 3 days ago.

Comment: yeah but they provide the answer using jquery not using java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can access CSS classes through GWT code but not its class attributes through setStyleName(String) method. For example

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setStyleName("Stylename");
```

for example css of

```
.StyleName {
 background : #abcdef;
 }
```

Further you can change the value of some attributes without css like

```
button.setWidth("100px");
button.setHeight("20px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SAC : http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/Overview.en.html

Comment: If you are familiar with SAX ( Simple API for XML) then this will get you started: http://www.w3.org/TR/SAC/DemoSAC.java , the SAC notifies you of the occurence of "tokens" in CSS, and its simple to use once you get hold of it.